# convert iis rewrite to nginx

Tags: nginx, iis-7, url-rewriting

New to nginx, totally confused.

How to convert this URL rewrite to nginx?

```
<rule name="Redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(about-us|sites\/company.com|item1|item2|item3)/.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://backend.com/<which ever link they decide to click on>" />
</rule>
```

Thanks and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` documentation.

> The ngx_http_rewrite_module module is used to change request URI using regular expressions, return redirects, and conditionally select configurations.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: Thanks Tan! I have read this article but I'm still a little confused on how to convert multiple URLs to redirect.  I'm able to redirect one URL at a time ie. location /about-us { rewrite ^ https://company2.com$request_uri redirect;}  Do I need to do this for each URLs then? or can I use one location to rewrite multiple URLs?  Thank you again!